# My USB flash drives are dying quickly, why?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

My pendrives are dying like flies in winter. And I am not using them much, like I flash maybe 20 times some OS iso into it and overwritten it with files like maybe 20-30 times. And it's dead again. Also, I was using BTRFS filesystem on it (write once) and also I've been zeroing free space on them occasionally.

To my knowledge, pendrives are using dynamic wear levelling which takes advantage of free space. But I think there's a catch - how the pendrive knows which space is free if there's no TRIM command on pendrives? So once the drive becomes full, even the files are deleted, the free space is treated as used and so wear levelling should not work, am I wrong?

I got idea, that maybe partitioning pendrive to it's 50% capacity would leave plenty of unused space for wear levelling, but there might be a catch - wear levelling might not work because the distance is too big - the other half might be on different chip and wear levelling might not work across different chips, which I think in case of simple dynamic wear levelling can be the problem.

So what are the other options for extending the wear on the flash drives? I think maybe a trick to zero the deleted files would work, is it something  like that available on Linux and NTFS partition? Or zeroing it manually by cat /dev/zero or something? How something like that can be done on encrypted flash drive with LUKS2?

I also heard that flash chips used for pendrives are the worst parts not suitable for other use like SSD or mobiles, can this be true?

Comment: Wear leveling is built into the firmware on the flash drive, depending on the quality of the pen drive how long it will last, this varies widely.

Comment: There are also plenty of drives that misrepresent how much data they can hold, this is a well known scam. So your 32 GB pen drive may just hold a single GB and overwrite existing data. Buying them from a well known supplier (and crossing your fingers) seems required.